installing sp112 ubuntu 24.04
I've successfully managed to install my printer following this tutorial
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/installer_imprimante_ricoh#modeles_sp-112_sp_204_et_sp_201n
But when i try to print a document, the system tells me the print is over but nothing append on the printer
Could you help me with that please?
